# Stopping a thread once condition matches

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to trigger `upfunction` and stop when it writes 3 in the filename. Basically I want to stop a thread once the condition is met as shown below.

```
def getstatus():
    fh = open(filename,'r')
    return fh.read()

def  upfunction(arg):

    for i in range(arg):
        print ("backup running")
        print(getstatus())
        target = open(filename, 'w')
        target.write(str(i))
        sleep(1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target = upfunction, args = (10, ))
    thread.start()
    print(getstatus())
    while getstatus() != "3":
        print("NOT 3 ")
        sleep(0.5)
        continue


    thread.stop()
    print("thread finished...exiting")
```

It shows

> AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute 'stop'

Please see me as newbie to python. 
Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

'Thread' object has no attribute 'stop' is helpful answer from python interpretator to you

You should place thread termination condition to **upfunction**.

```
    def  upfunction(arg):
        i = 0
        while getstatus() != "3":
            print ("backup running")
            print(getstatus())
            target = open(filename, 'w')
            target.write(str(i))
            i += 1
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target = upfunction, args = (10, ))
    thread.start()
    print(getstatus())
    print("thread finished...exiting")
```

Comment: @erip i'm agree with you, but for newbie my answer is more understandable, IMHO

Answer (score 1):

you can just use threading deamon method to kill this new thread.

```
thread.start()
thread.deamon()
```

when the main threads ends this custom threads also dies .so there is no need of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some explanation about the right way to do that: [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python).

And as Lex said [[0]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34924297/5222966), you can add a condition (in `upfunction` arguments) to stop your target function.